# Error compiling with boost library tools/root

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, compiler-errors

I recently downloaded the boost library on ubuntu with apt-get.

I have written the following code, which defines a unary functor and then attempts to find it's root with the boost library (I put it all in main.cpp just for now and split it up later):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/distributions/binomial.hpp>
#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>


class MyBinom {
public:
    MyBinom(int B, int N, int ans);

    double operator()(const double x) const;

private:
    int B;
    int N;
    double ans;
};

MyBinom::MyBinom(int B, int N, int ans) : B(B), N(N), ans(ans) {}

double MyBinom::operator()(const double x) const {
    boost::math::binomial dist(N, x);
    double distans = boost::math::cdf(dist, B) - ans;
    return distans;
}


int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Result;

    MyBinom myBinom95(75, 4167, 0.95); // Create the Class with the unary operator.

    boost::uintmax_t max_iter=500; // Set max iterations.

    boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double> tol(30); //Set the eps tolerance.

    Result r1 = boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(myBinom95, 0, 1, tol, max_iter); // use the toms solve algorithm.

    std::cout << "Let's take a look at the root" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "root bracketed: [ " << r1.first << " , " << r1.second <<  " ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f("<< r1.first << ")=" << myBinom95(r1.first) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f("<< r1.second << ")=" << myBinom95(r1.second) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max_iter=" << max_iter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I definitely know my unary operator works since I compiled and ran an example that just ran the operator with an arbitrary value of x.

However the above code does not compile properly and I'm new to boost and am not sure why.

I compile with:

```
$ g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
```

However I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/roots.hpp:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/detail/igamma_inverse.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:1528,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/distributions/binomial.hpp:83,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp: In function 'std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&, const Policy&) [with F = MyBinom, T = int, Tol = boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>, Policy = boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>, uintmax_t = long unsigned int]':
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:475:71:   instantiated from 'std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&) [with F = MyBinom, T = int, Tol = boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>, uintmax_t = long unsigned int]'
main.cpp:37:81:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:467:81: error: no matching function for call to 'toms748_solve(MyBinom&, const int&, const int&, double, double, boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>&, uintmax_t&, const boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy>&)'
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:467:81: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:283:17: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol, class Policy> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&, const Policy&)
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:458:24: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&)
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:464:24: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol, class Policy> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&, const Policy&)
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/toms748_solve.hpp:473:24: note: template<class F, class T, class Tol> std::pair<T, T> boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(F, const T&, const T&, Tol, uintmax_t&)
```

I'm still getting used to compiler errors but it seems it's not finding the function: boost::math::tools::toms748_solve?

Is this an error because I'm not building and compiling right (something I need to build or link in?) or is it my syntax is rubbish?

**--EDIT/ADDENUM--**

The code now works as per sehe's answer, the output is:

```
Lets take a look at the root
root bracketed: [ 1 , 1 ]
f(1)=0
f(1)=0
max_iter=2
```

However this does not agree with the same calculation by the prototype R code I used before trying to finish it in C++:

```
> binomcalc <- function(p, p0, N, B){pbinom(B,N,p)-p0}
> uniroot(binomcalc, c(0,1), p0=0.05, B=75, N=4167)
$root
[1] 0.02178983

$f.root
[1] -0.0009172035

$iter
[1] 12

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

I'm wondering why they are different? Do I need to adjust something like the tolerance or precision?

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My compiler mentions

```
\usr\include\boost\math\tools\toms748_solve.hpp|283 col 17| note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
\usr\include\boost\math\tools\toms748_solve.hpp|468 col 81| note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const T' ('int' and 'double')
```

So... that's pretty clear :) Fix it:

```
Result r1 = boost::math::tools::toms748_solve(myBinom95, 0., 1., tol, max_iter); // use the toms solve algorithm.
```

Output:

```
Let's take a look at the root
root bracketed: [ 1 , 1 ]
f(1)=0
f(1)=0
max_iter=2
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9245cc1d41c5eb00)**

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to improve the accuracy? I've updated the original question with the working version.

Comment: Yeah. You should however post new questions as separate questions.

Comment: Very true, I can change this - I wonder if SO or the boost mail list would be better

Comment: I'd say here/but I'm biased :)